# Convert year into datetime format pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
Name       Birth_Year
Messi      2007
Ronaldo    2004
```

I would like to convert that Birth_Year into date.

Expected Output

```
Name    Birt_Year      Birth_Date
Messi   2007.0         2007-01-01
Ronaldo 2004.0         2004-01-01
```

I tried below code

```
df1['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Birt_Year'], format='%Y%m%d.0', errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there, your format is just `%Y`, since you only have year on your `Birth_Year` column:

```
df['Birth_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Birth_Year'], format='%Y')

      Name  Birth_Year Birth_Date
0    Messi        2007 2007-01-01
1  Ronaldo        2004 2004-01-01
```